# What's the warning on line 736?

Tags: warnings

on my wp5.03 (though warnings were thrown Jan 7 and 19 so 5.02 or )

from public_html/error_log

PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 736

anyone else?

Comment: Have you turned off all the plugins and switched to a default theme, to ensure that it is, in fact, WordPress (and not a plugin or a theme) that's throwing the error?

Comment: Thanks Pat, that's the first thing I thought about, however, as the error isn't fatal, and as the error has only happened a few times in the past month, turning things off or changing themes on the production site isn't an option atm.  I'll keep a watch on this post though.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L736), the 736 line of that file contains:

```
$qv['name'] = trim( $qv['name'] );
```

And `$qv` is defined as:

```
$this->query_vars = $this->fill_query_vars($this->query_vars);
$qv = &$this->query_vars;
```

So... That means, that you use WP_Query incorrectly somewhere in your code...

You should pass string value as name param, and it looks like somewhere in your site an array is passed as that param...

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek ... 'Somewhere in your site' is a big place and I just took this project on ... any chance of me narrowing it down to a dir or two ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid not. At least not based on what you've posted here.

Comment: Try hitting the major pages, homepage, an internal page, archive, single post, see which of those triggers that same error to help narrow it down. Also, if you bring this locally, you can install and activate [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).